# Cakephp how to set root page from admin folder?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

Routes.php

```
$routes->scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $builder) {
    $builder->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
    $builder->connect('/pages/*', 'Pages::display');
    $builder->fallbacks();
});
```

File structure

[image]

How to add Admin login page as root page of the website?

Something like this

```
   $routes->scope('/Admin/UserController', function (RouteBuilder $builder) {
       $builder->connect('/Admin/UserController', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
   });
```

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you're supposed to connect routes, you don't put stuff like `UserController` in your path, the path defines the URL format!

If you want to connect `/` to your admin prefixed controller, then you need to pass the `prefix` option in the route defaults accordingly, for example:

```php
$routes->scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $builder) {
    // connect the URL `/` to `\App\Controller\Admin\UsersController::login()`
    $builder->connect('/', [
        'prefix' => 'Admin',
        'controller' => 'Users',
        'action' => 'login',
    ]);
    // shorthand variant of the above
    // $builder->connect('/', 'Admin/Users::login');

    $builder->connect('/pages/*', 'Pages::display');
    $builder->fallbacks();
});
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Connecting Routes](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/routing.html#routes-configuration)**